# Como puedo darle un margen al texto del checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3, asp.net-mvc

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
  var fieldSet = "<div class='checkbox'><label><input " + propRequired + " data-is-common-control-note='" + IsCommonControlNote + "' data-is-required='" + IsRequired + "' class='input-details' type='checkbox' " + isDisabled + " id='"+id+"-" +
                ControlId + "' control-type='" +
                ControlType + "' name='" + ControlId + "' value='" + ControlName + "'>";

            if (ControlCaption !== "") {
                fieldSet = fieldSet + ControlCaption;
            }
            else {
                fieldSet = fieldSet + PhysicalName;
            }

            fieldSet = fieldSet + "</label></div>";

            var html = '<div control-type="' +
                ControlType + '" name="' +
                ControlName + '" data-field="' +
                PhysicalName + '" style="position:absolute; z-index:' + zIndex + "; left:" +
                ControlLeft + 'px; top:' +
                ControlTop + 'px; height: ' +
                ControlHeight + 'px; width:' +
                ControlWidth + 'px;">' + fieldSet + '</div>';
            $(html).appendTo(ContainerId);
```

Al ejecutarse ese bloque de codigo los checkboxs me salen de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que podria hacer para que el texto no me salga tan pegado????

Aqui un fragmento del codigo html:

```
<div control-type="TIssCheckBox" name="IssCheckBox13" data-  field="IssCheckBox13" style="position:absolute; z-index:0; left:8px; top:2877px; height: 17px; width:97px;">
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
          <input data-is-common-control-note="" data-is-required="" class="input-details" disabled="disabled" id="Mother-7710" control-type="TIssCheckBox" name="7710" value="IssCheckBox13" type="checkbox">
             Mother
       </label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el css o al menos el html ya resultante? Tu pregunta puede ser calificada como de **"baja calidad"** y ser cerrada por moderadores por eso. Con respecto al porque asumo que puede ser un conflicto con el css, igual puedes probar agregarle un `margin-right: Xpx`, pero creería que es porque esta siendo posicionado de forma absoluta en el css o tiene un margen negativo a la derecha. Ya que por lo general no deberían estar sobrepuestos, pero con solo la imagen es muy difícil de saber.

Comment: Puedes meter el texto en una etiqueta <label> y utilizar el CSS para darle un margin.

Comment: Como mensiono @EdgarGutierrez, si mostrar el html final que genera tu codigo pudriamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

porque no usas lo tradicional algo asi:

```
<input type="checkbox"><label>Option One</label>
<input type="checkbox"><label>Option Two</label>
<input type="checkbox"><label>Option Three</label>
```

**resultado**
[image: resultado]

ya con ello le puedes agregar estilos css a tu gusto
Dicho de otra forma primero va el **input type checkbox** luego el **label**

Comment: fuente : https://jsfiddle.net/e0ajet48/2/

Comment: El problema de usarlo de la forma que lo tengo es que los checkbox los creo de el resultado de una consulta hacia la BD, la cual devuelve una cadena, a la cual le hago split y cada posicion del arreglo seria un checkbox, podria hacerlo de tu forma aun asi??

Comment: claro que puedes hacerlo pero como te digo primero va el input luego el label ..!!

Comment: probare asi como me sugieres ahora

Comment: Perfecto man gracias

Answer (score 0):

En tu codigo se ve que el `input[checkbox]` esta dentro del `label` y a la derecha del `checkbox` esta el texto. Intenta asignandole un `margin-left` al `checkbox` para que el texto se separe del checkbox:

```css
.checkbox{
  display:inline;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
.checkbox input{
  margin-right:5px; /*<- separando el checkbox del texto */
  vertical-align: middle; /*<- centrando el checkbox en el medio */
}
```

```html
<div class='checkbox'>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Texto 1
  </label>
</div>

<div class='checkbox'>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Texto 2
</div>

<div class='checkbox'>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Texto 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: intente eso hace unos instantes pero el tamaño del div donde esta no me deja correrlo a la derecha, ese tamaño y los demas datos del div como el height, el left el top viene de la BD y no puedo cambiarlo